# Prolog: Element not present in list

Tags: list, search, prolog

I need find element position in list (as the built-in predicate nth, but here the first element has index 1). But, I need also have an output like 'Element is not present' if not.
I try a solution not so elegant, assigning a big value to counter.
But it's not the correct solution!!!
I'm afraid it's very easy but I can't find another solution !!!

Can anyone helps me?

```
search(L):-
      write('searching for: '),read(E),find(L,E,Pos),
      out(L,E,Pos),!.

out(E,Pos):-
          Pos < 10000,
          write('element '),write(E),write(' is in position n. '),write(Pos),!.

out(E,Pos):-
          Pos > 10000,
          write('Element '),write(E),write(' is not present!'),!.

find([X|Xs],E,Pos):-
                 X \= E,
                 find(Xs,E,Pos1),
                 Pos is Pos1 + 1.
find([],_,10000).
find([X],X,1).
find([X|_],X,Pos):-
                Pos is 1,!.
```

Comment: How about using value 0 to denote a missing item?  Your first element has index 1, so this would seem to be a safe option.

Comment: Because in tail recursion prolog executes the row "Pos is Pos1 + 1." in each case.

Comment: I don't propose using 0 in the tail recursion, only as a return value, which is what I thought you sought instead of the "big value".  See the answer by Raceimaztion as to how *anything* can be returned for the missing item case.  That answer's code doesn't happen to be tail recursive, but that could be fixed up by using an auxiliary predicate.  However if you are satisfied with the "Just let it fail" answer by z5h, that is certainly elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is more something like this:

```
search(L):-
    write('searching for: '),read(E),
    finde(E).

finde(E) :-
    find(L,E,Pos), % find succeeds 
    out(L,E,Pos),!. % and prints, cut ensures we don't try next clause

finde(E) :- write('Element '),write(E),write(' is not present!'),!. % called if not found
```

That way you don't need a strange find clause that always succeeds with a large number. Just let it fail.

Comment: I think your answer is very efficient! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you're not limited to returning numbers from your find/3 predicate.

You can instead return any other atom, like so:

```
find([], _, notfound).
find([H|_], H, 1) :- !
find([_|T], H, Pos) :-
        find(T, H, Found),
        (
            integer(Found), !,
            Pos is Found+1
        );(
            Pos = notfound
        ).
```

However, this style is a little more awkward to write with, though your return value is much more descriptive.

Edited to fix an error.

Comment: You might also enable tail recursion, e.g. using **find/4** that has the possibility of failing and **find/3** that returns a descriptive or zero value in a fall-through case on missing items.

Comment: I don't understand... in my swi-prolog i've this output:
15 ?- find([2,3,4],2,Pos).
Pos = 1.
16 ?- find([2,3,4],3,Pos).
ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
17 ?- find([2,3,4],4,Pos).
ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
18 ?- find([2,3,4],5,Pos).<br/>
Pos = notfound.<br/></p>

Comment: @hardmath, @Aleg, Bah, that's what I get for writing it up without testing. I've fixed it now, though I now see that it's not the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
search(L):-
        write('searching for: '),
        read(E),
        find(L,E,Pos),
        fail.
search(_).

find(L,E,0) :-
        \+(append(_,[E|_],L)),!.
find(L,E,Pos) :-
        append(L0,[E|_],L),
        length(L0,Len0),
        Pos is Len + 1.
find(_,_,-1).

out(E,0) :-
        writef('element %t is not present. ',[E]),!.
out(E,-1) :-
        writef('element %t is no longer present. ',[E]),!.
out(E,Pos) :-
        writef('element %t is in position %t. ',[E,Pos]),!.
```

Comment: There seems to be a typo in the second rule/clause for **find/3**.  The variable Len has not been bound when you compute Pos, so presumably you meant Len0 here (bound in the previous subgoal).

Answer (score 0):

```
% NewLine was missing.

out(E,0) :-
        writef('element %t is not present. \n',[E]),!.
out(E,-1) :-
        writef('element %t is no longer present. \n',[E]),!.
out(E,Pos) :-
        writef('element %t is in position %t. \n',[E,Pos]),!.
```